# cant find previous written data into a combobox

Tags: c#, user-interface, combobox, save

i have data which will be written in a text file and then transferred to a combobox via a buton.
But the next time i start the gui , I cant find the previous written data in combobox.
Anyway to save the data in combobox?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Could you post some code for us to see please?

Comment: I have a textbox, a button and a combobox. when i enter text in the box it wil be sent to the combobox and then i proceed with my gui .
but when i start the gui again, i want the previous written text to be already in the combobox. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there are a lot of ways. I would recommend using the `<appSettings>` in the `app.config` file. You can read those settings easily. First, add a reference to `System.Configuration`. Next, build a few extension methods to make the process easier:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetValue(this KeyValueConfigurationCollection o,
        string key,
        string val)
    {
        if (!o.AllKeys.Contains(key)) { o.Add(key, val); }
        else { o[key].Value = val; }
    }

    public static string GetValue(this NameValueCollection o,
        string key,
        object defaultVal = null)
    {
        if (!o.AllKeys.Contains(key)) { return Convert.ToString(defaultVal); }
        return o[key];
    }
}
```

Next, when you want to get the value from the settings, do this:

```
var val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValue("ComboBoxValue");
```

and then, when you want to set the value, do this:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var app = config.AppSettings.Settings;

app.SetValue("ComboBoxValue", comboBox.Text);

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: Its actually tough to understand , any document which might help me understand it better ?

Comment: @user2862843, tell me what you don't understand and let me address that.

Comment: Where to use the extension 
tried it in my code, lot of errors

Comment: @user2862843, build a new `.cs` file named `Extensions`. Change the `namespace` to `System`. Paste in the `static class` I provided named `Extensions`. At that point, all of the extension methods will be available.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to automatically preserve the content of comboboxes if you restart your application.
You have to reload the data each time.

Comment: What should i use in order to save my data ? I mean any other method ?

Answer (score 0):

First create a setting named Combovalues of type stringCollection and Scope to user(if u need add some values to it) then use this code(this is a skeletal code,validation and other rules for saving and deleting are of your choice to apply):

```
        private BindingSource bs;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.Combovalues;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
        }

        //button1 is for adding values.
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                bs.Add(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //this will persist to disk the changes made
            //in this application session.
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        //button2 is for deleting values
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //removes the currently selected item in the combobox.
            bs.RemoveCurrent();
        }
```